# "window.location.hash = location.hash" does not work in Webkit (Safari & Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I can't get `window.location.hash = location.hash` to work in Safari.

I'm using javascript to wrap the contents of my page with a scrollable DIV, placed below the navigation bar in my webpage.  Since the scrollbar's location gets reset when the javascript runs, I'm losing the original hash location that the URL set. I need to re-cue the hash location **without** reloading the page using javascript, so I'm using `window.location.hash = location.hash`.  It works in IE8, Firefox, and Opera, but it doesn't work in Safari. (I'll assume Chrome, too, but I haven't check).  Any suggestions?

*Hint: I like jQuery.*

Comment: Define "doesn't work", please.

Comment: @Tomalak As far as I can tell, that line of code never executes in Safari. (1) The wrapper javascript executes, resetting the scrollbar location to the top of the page. (2) An alert appears, telling me the `window...hash` function is the next thing to run on the page... and that's it.  Nothing else (pertinent) happens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Webkit has two oddities that prevent `window.location.hash = location.hash` from working normally.

1. Webkit responds to `window.location.href` instead of `window.location.hash` (like all the other browsers do).  Curiously, `webkit` can still read the URL's `hash` tag using `location.hash`
2. Webkit has a documented bug where the href `location` has to be set to the same location twice before the browser will go to the new location.  Bug report [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2005/06/Setting_locationhash_to_the_same_value_twice_cause.html).

This code solved my problem: (using jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    gotoHASH()
};

function gotoHASH() {
    if (location.hash) {
        if ( $.browser.webkit == false ) {
            window.location.hash = location.hash;
        } else {
            window.location.href = location.hash;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 10):

I ended up with

```
window.location.hash = "";
window.location.hash = "myanchor";
```

This worked fine in all desktop browsers I tested in and on iOS and Android chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Set location.hash to something else first and immediately set it back.

```
var t = window.location.hash;
window.location.hash = "non-existant-id";
window.location.hash = t;
```

Comment: No cigar. Your code only modified the URL hash tag. It never moved the page.

Answer (score 0):

Before JavaScript changes the orginal hash location, get the scroll position using

```
var st = $(window).scrollTop().
```

When you want to restore the scroll location, use

```
$(window).scrollTop(st);
```

Comment: `var st = $(window).scrollTop()` doesn't even set the variable in Safari.  When I run `$(window).scrollTop(st)`, the console gives me a variable undefined error. (The code works in other browsers, though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
go_hash('#home')
```

> The function...

```
function go_hash(hash) {
  console.log('go_hash: ' + hash)
  if(hash.indexOf('#') == -1)
    hash = '#' + hash
  if(document.location.hash) {
    document.location.hash = hash
    return
  }
  if(window.location.hash) {
    window.location.hash = hash
    return
  }
  if(document.location.href) {
    document.location.href = hash
    return
  }
  window.location.href = hash
}
```