# window.location.hash not returning anything on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

No matter what is passed on the url, window.location.hash returns nothing on iPhone safari, but works well on other devices and pc browser.

```
var testhash =window.location.hash;
alert(testhash);
```

if I redirect to

`window.location.href = "example.com/somepage.php?param=1#googletranlsate"`

On iphone I'm redirected to

`window.location.href = "example.com/somepage.php?param=1"`

Is there any issue specific to iphone or safari I dont know of?

Thanks

Comment: Try window.location.href. [\[Source\]][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970769/window-location-hash-location-hash-does-not-work-in-webkit-safari-chrome

Comment: @SFox I edited the question as I believe those are different issues. Thanks