# video-js iPhone ended / fullscreenchange events not firing?

Tags: iphone, html5-video

I am using [video-js](http://www.videojs.com/) library, but I cannot get either the `fullscreenchange` or `ended` events to fire on iPhone as it uses the native player. Are there any workarounds for this?

```
main_video_player.on('ended', function () {
    window.location.hash = '#share';
});

main_video_player.on('fullscreenchange', function () {
    window.location.hash = '#share';
});
```

EDIT:

I have tried this with some success, but it is not firing on my iphone 4 simulator:

```
$('video#main-video_html5_api').on('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    window.location.hash = '#share';
});
```

EDIT 2: Could it be that the hash change won't work on iPhone if the player is fullscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather bizarrely this turned out to be a bug with changing the window.location.hash on the iPhone

This doesn't work;

```
$('video#main-video_html5_api').on('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    window.location.hash = '#share';
});
```

This does!

```
$('video#main-video_html5_api').on('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    window.location.hash = '#';
    window.location.hash = '#share';
});
```

This answer helped me in the right direction: ["window.location.hash = location.hash" does not work in Webkit (Safari & Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970769/window-location-hash-location-hash-does-not-work-in-webkit-safari-chrome#answer-6975488)